# Error in Dynamic SQL Command which using Insert by Select Statement

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am using this procedure to select the values from different tables (each week each table) and Insert them in one temporary table and get them as output by selecting the table at the end of the procedure...

```
CREATE proc salessample (@tablename varchar(50), @did varchar(50))      
as      
begin      
   create table #salesdetail(sno int identity, This_Week_Left float,
                             This_Week_Right float, Last_Week_Left float, 
                             Last_Week_Right float, Paid_Left float,
                             Paid_Right float, Paid float, orbitrate float)      

DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(500), @i int;
DECLARE @SQLString2 NVARCHAR(500);      

set @i=1      

--while(@i < 2)      
--begin      

set @SQLString = N'insert into #salesdetail(This_Week_Left,This_Week_Right,Last_Week_Left,Last_Week_Right,Paid_Left,Paid_Right,Paid,orbitrate) select a.This_Week_Left,a.This_Week_Right,a.Last_Week_Left,a.Last_Week_Right,a.Paid_Left,a.Paid_Right,a.Paid,b.orbitrate from Power.Week_'+@tablename +'_table a, Power.Orbit_Rates b where a.m_distributor_id ='+@did+' and b.week_details ='+convert(numeric(18),@tablename);      

exec  sp_executesql @SQLString      

set @i =@i + 1      

--end      

select * from #salesdetail      

end
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the problem you're getting?

Comment: Concur with the above statement, hence the -1. Happy to revoke it when more info is provided.

Answer (score 1):

What is the error message that you are getting. You question is impossible to answer in its current form.

As far as i can see it could be one of the following potential problems:

1. conversioons between unicode (nvarchar) and non-unicode (varchar)
2. Converting to a number and then appending to a string:

   `... and b.week_details ='+convert(numeric(18),@tablename);`
3. Converting to numeric(18)
4. Some other insertion error that I can't see

Break the dynamic SQL statement down into parts, and view it before attempting to `exec` it. I.e. `print` or `select` the string. You can the copy it and run it standalone to see if there are any problems.

**EDIT**

From your comment below, I can see that your problem is that you are converting a string to a number and then attempting to append it to a string. Try this instead:

```
... and b.week_details ='+ @tablename
```

Comment: The error i m getting is Arthimetic overflow when try to convert varchar value to int datatype.....

Answer (score 0):

Thanks U all...... For all answers and comments.....

I got Cleared My error..

I forgot to give single quotes for where clause data in Dyanmic command...

like this ....

''' Text ''' = 'Text'....

the reason Why I got error was it accepts the parameter and executes in the procedure.
but not for all values. I gave table name as input .

Now its Working . Thank s Once again